# Vertical scrolling inside the vertical scrolling in steps - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview, react-native-sectionlist

I need to create the following interface:

1. There is a parent `SectionList` in which there are various sections of elements
2. One of these sections contains a vertical `FlatList`.

I want `SectionList` to scroll vertically strictly by sections (e.g. via `scrollToLocation`), while vertical `FlatList` should scroll freely within itself and be independent of `SectionList` scrolling

Below is a schematic of how this should look visually.

[image: Example]

Maybe you need to use neither `SectionList` nor `FlatList` to solve this problem, this is my vision of how it can be implemented. Who has any ideas how to solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

I created an example of my code in [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@slam_ua/vertical-scrolling-inside-the-vertical-scrolling-in-steps). The problems I can't solve yet:

1. How to make the SectionList scroll strictly by section.
2. As you can see, there is 1 common scroll on SectionList and FlatList and that is not what I need.  The scrolling of both lists should be independent (if I scroll FlatList, the parent SectionList should not move). I tried using nestedScrollEnabled, but this option does nothing (or I'm using it wrong).

Answer (score 1):

I think that your approach will work, the only problem you might face is the inner scrollable component not scrolling on android but you can fix it by adding `nestedScrollEnabled` prop to the scrollable view (in the parent, although I might be mistaken, in that case you'll have to add it to the child)

Edit:

```
          else {
            return (
              <View style={{ padding: SPACING, backgroundColor: COLORS[item] }}>
                <ScrollView
                  nestedScrollEnabled={true}
                  style={{ ...styles.flatlist, height: 100 }}>
                  {COUNT.map((item) => (
                    <View key={item}>
                      <Text>{item}</Text>
                    </View>
                  ))}
                </ScrollView>
              </View>
            );
          }
```

https://snack.expo.dev/@rodsar/952354 here is a working example, FlatList didn't seem to work for me in this case and i haven't investigated the causes, but ScrollView did work.

Comment: See the update to my question, I added the example code to Snack. So far I'm having trouble separating scrollable lists, maybe you can help.

Comment: I updated my answer, please try it out and mark it as solved if it helped you, as for scrollToLocation there are many approaches online that you can try to implement first.

Comment: Cool, I get your approach, but there is one problem. When scrolling `ScrollView`, when scrolling comes to the end this event goes to the parent `SectionList`. Even if I set `scrollEnabled={false}` option in `SectionList`, because `ScrollView` scrolls and the event propagates to the parent `SectionList` will still scroll. I hope I explained the point clearly :)

Comment: I think that's for the better, so that the user can continue scrolling down once they hit the end of the section, but you can override this behavior by disabling section scroll when the user is scrolling on the scroll view and then enable it again when the drag ends, but sadly I don't have the time for it now :(

Answer (score 0):

Nesting of `scrollable` doesn’t work as expected when in the same direction.

I will suggest you `FlatList` from `react-native-gesture-handler`

[snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@fanish/vertical-scrolling-inside-the-vertical-scrolling-in-steps)

```
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```

ref: [react-native-gesture-handler/FlatList](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/2.1.1/gesture-handlers/basics/about-handlers/#using-native-components)

Comment: That's not exactly what I need. This, unfortunately, does not fully resolve the issue

Comment: Can you explain what doesn't work with my solution

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using `RN 0.66`, `react-native-gesture-handler` v2. Ended up using the `<GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>` wrapping the `App` as described here:

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/installation/

and the `FlatList` and `ScrollView` exported by RNGH

`import { FlatList, ScrollView } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';`

```
<SectionList
        contentContainerStyle={styles.sectionListContainer}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        SectionSeparatorComponent={SeparatorItem}
        sections={mySections}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={renderFlatlist}. // <-- using RNGH FlatList in that function
        renderScrollComponent={(props) => <ScrollView {...props} />} // <--using RNGH ScrollView here
        renderSectionHeader={({ section: { title } }) => (
          <Title>{title}</Title>
        )}
        stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
 />
```